# wave file export is corrupted

Tags: c++, format, export, wave

I wrote two functions which should export an audio-float buffer into a .wav-file, but I have problems with playing the exported file. Audacity plays it like it should be (sounds exactly like within my application), however, Ableton (DAW-software) seems to misinterprets some part of the wav so it sounds realy distorted. (like a distortion-effekt)

I guess that ableton somehow assumes a wrong sample-depth (smaller) so the actuall samples blow the limits.

I have two functions, the one creates an `int32_t` buffer from two float-buffers (mixing left and right into one buffer), the other function writes the .wav-file, including the format chunk etc. I guess that somewhere there is the problem.

**class members / structs**

```cpp
// static I use in the export function
static const int FORMAT_PCM = 1;
static const int CHANNEL_COUNT = 2;    // fix stereo
static const int BYTES_PER_SAMPLE = 4; // fix bytes per sample, 32bit audio

// a function I found in the internet, helps writting the bytes to the file
template <typename T>
static void write(std::ofstream& stream, const T& t) {
    stream.write((const char*)&t, sizeof(T));
};

// used "structure" to store the buffer
class StereoAudioBuffer {
public:
    StereoAudioBuffer(int length) : sizeInSamples(2*length){
        samples = new int32_t[2*length];
    };
    ~StereoAudioBuffer() {delete samples;};

    int32_t *samples;
    const int sizeInSamples;
};
```

**converting function**

```cpp
StereoAudioBuffer* WaveExport::convertTo32BitStereo(
        float *leftSamples, 
        float*rightSamples, 
        int length) 
{
    StereoAudioBuffer *buffer = new StereoAudioBuffer(length);
    float max = 0;

    // find max sample 
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if(abs(leftSamples[i]) > max) {
            max = abs(leftSamples[i]);
        }
        if(abs(rightSamples[i]) > max) {
            max = abs(rightSamples[i]);
        }
    }



    // normalise and scale to size(int32_t)

    float factor = 2147483000.0f / max;

    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        buffer->samples[2*i] = leftSamples[i] * factor ;
        buffer->samples[2*i+1] = rightSamples[i] * factor;
    }
    return buffer;
}
```

**the exporting function** (part of this code comes from the internet, sadly, I can't find the source anymore

```cpp
void WaveExport::writeStereoWave(
        const char *path, 
        StereoAudioBuffer* buffer, 
        int sampleRate) 
{
    std::ofstream stream(path, std::ios::binary);

    // RIFF
    stream.write("RIFF", 4);

    // FILE SIZE
    write<int>(stream, 36 + buffer->sizeInSamples * BYTES_PER_SAMPLE); // 32 bits -> 4 bytes

    // WAVE
    stream.write("WAVE", 4);

    // FORMAT CHUNK
    stream.write("fmt ", 4);

    write<int>(stream, 16);

    write<short>(stream, FORMAT_PCM);                                       // Format
    write<short>(stream, CHANNEL_COUNT);                                    // Channels
    write<int>(stream, sampleRate);                                         // Sample Rate
    write<int>(stream, sampleRate * CHANNEL_COUNT * BYTES_PER_SAMPLE);      // Byterate
    write<short>(stream, CHANNEL_COUNT * BYTES_PER_SAMPLE);                 // Frame size
    write<short>(stream, 8 * BYTES_PER_SAMPLE);                             // Bits per sample

    int dataChunkSize = buffer->sizeInSamples * BYTES_PER_SAMPLE;
    // SAMPLES
    stream.write("data", 4);
    stream.write((const char*)&dataChunkSize, 4);
    stream.write((const char*)buffer->samples, BYTES_PER_SAMPLE*buffer->sizeInSamples);
}
```

Does anybody know how to write .wav files and maybe can tell me what I did wrong or missed? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was no problem. I used 32bit .wav which just wasn't supported in the application, I used for playback.

I changed the export functions to use int16_t, 16bit depth, and it works fine.